# Memory leak when using CString for tree node

Tags: c++, visual-c++, tree, mfc

I would like to save (serialize) an MFC tree control in a dialog and recall it to populate the tree when the dialog is initialized.  I thought the way to approach that task would be to first code a program that creates a (preferably) vector representation of the tree, stores it in a text file, and then recreates the tree representation by deserializing from the saved file.  I would also prefer to save the nodes as CStrings because that’s how I’m used to saving and reading text from files.  However, not only can I not get to first base on this, I can’t even pick up the bat.  The following minimal code to create a single node using std::string runs ok.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
// A node of N-ary tree 
struct Node {
    std::string key;
    std::vector<Node*> child;  // An array of pointers for children 
};
// A utility function to create a new N-ary tree node 
Node* newNode(std::string key)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    return temp;
}
// A utility function to create a tree
Node* createTree()
{
Node* root = newNode( "Root" );
return root;
}
int main()
{
    Node* root = createTree();
    return 0;    
}
```

But if I change it to use CString instead,

```
#include <afx.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
struct Node {
    CString key;
    std::vector<Node*> child;  // An array of pointers for children 
};
Node* newNode(CString key)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->key = key;
    return temp;
}
Node* createTree()
{
    Node* root = newNode( _T("Root") );
    return root;
}
```

…when the program exits it reports a memory leak. Could someone please explain why, and what if anything I can do to correct it?

Comment: Does `CString` always occupy the same size in that struct?

Comment: You have memory leak in both cases. You have a `new` operator with no corresponding `delete` operator. Visual Studio will not report the memory leak by default. Your `std::string` example doesn't report a leak, but the leak is still there. MFC setup will report memory leaks by default, so your `CString` example reports the leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the previous answer and comments noted, someone has to free all allocated memory.

When you use `new`, the responsibility is on you.

However, C++ provides smart pointers that can manage memory allocation and freeing for you; please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr.

Your sample code will look like this:

```
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
struct Node {
  CString key;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> child;  
};
std::unique_ptr<Node> newNode(CString key)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> temp = std::make_unique<Node>();
    temp->key = key;
    return temp;
}
std::unique_ptr<Node> createTree()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root = newNode(_T("Root"));
    root->child.push_back(newNode(_T("Child")));
    return root;
}
```

APPENDED per question in the comment:

```
CString encode(std::unique_ptr<Node>& root)
{
    if (root == nullptr)
        return _T("");
    {
        CString sRep = root->key;
        for (auto& temp : root->child)
            sRep += encode(temp);
        return sRep += _T("|");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that certainly works for what I had so far. But when I tried to write a function

        `CString encode(std::unique_ptr<Node> root)
        {
         if (root == nullptr) return _T("");
         {
          CString sRep = root->key;
          for (auto temp : root->child)
           sRep += encode(temp);
          return sRep += _T("|");
         }
        }`
called from `main()` by `CString sResult = encode(root)`, the compiler just laughs at me-- it says `root` in the calling statement and the `for()` statement is a deleted function.

Comment: @OldAndConfused - of course, you can't copy the unique pointer, BUT - you can pass it by reference. Please see my edits in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a memory leak in your original iteration as well (without using `CString`). You allocate memory on the heap for a `new Node` in `newNode(std::string)`, but you never call `delete` on that pointer anywhere.

Simply `delete root;` somewhere before `main()` exits to fix this first memory leak.

Next, you'll find that once you populate the `vector<Node*> child` with pointers, those will need to be deleted somehow as well. I suggest adding a destructor to your `struct Node` that iterates through vector and explicitly calls delete on each pointer in there.

### A note on `CString`

A quick search about how `CString` works[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/string-data-management?view=vs-2019) (because I've never dealt with it before) indicates that when you make a copy of a `CString` (such as by using the copy assignment operator), a new object isn't created, but a reference counter is incremented in the original `CString` object. The object is only destroyed once that reference counter reaches zero.

Since you're never calling `delete` on your Node pointer, the `CString` object in the Node object is never deleted, and this reference number is never decreased. Calling delete *should* fix the problem, but please report back whether or not it does.

Comment: Yes adding `delete root;` before `main()` exits evidently fixes the memory leak for this simple case of only creating the root node, even if it's a CString. But you're also correct that if additional nodes are created as descendants of `root`, they create garbage too. I suppose to clean them up, one would have to do a postorder traversal, deleting each node on the way. I'll have to look into how to do that.

Comment: I wondered about the use of `new` to create tree nodes, but as a _very_ inexpert coder, I guess I was distracted by the absence of any mention of destructors in any of the tree tutorials that pop up when you do a search for tree serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @OldAndConfused anything created with `new` must be cleaned up with `delete`. When an object is `delete`d, destructors are called on any member objects of the `delete`d object. In your case, the destructor for `child` WILL be called, and the memory for that vector will be cleaned up. If vector contained non-pointer objects, destructors would be called on those. But since they're pointers, the compiler does not call destructors. I'm not sure if this was a conscious design decision by the C++ devs or if it was a technical impossibility, but my assumption is the former.

Comment: Your explanation of how `CString` works doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @John This may be above my pay grade (or since I'm retired, above any pay grade I ever had). I thought it could be done with a postorder traversal, but all the examples I can find look like they do that by processing the tree top-down in a preorder traversal and pushing a _COPY_ of each node's key (value) into another container and then popping them out in reverse order and displaying them. This doesn't really give me a clue about how to delete the original tree in postorder sequence.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've never worked with CString before, so forgive me if the explanation doesn't make sense (or is downright wrong). It appears for CString as if the copy constructor doesn't allocate any new space (like copying a string would), it just increments an internal counter (like a shared_ptr) and the new object that is copied mostly contains a pointer to the already-allocated memory.

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct and sufficient. Any c++ object will need its own memory, either on heap or stack, this has to be cleaned up at some point. The `CString` documentation, which you have referenced, talks about *"CString Reference Counting"*, I don't think that's relevant here. Note that the original question makes a wrong assumption about `CString`. The asker has different project setups for `CString` and `std::string`. One project is reporting the leak, the other project is not reporting the leak.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani There's a line of code in the OP's post with `temp->key = key;`. Where both `key` and `temp->key` are CString objects. This should invoke the assignment operator which would increment the reference counter.

Comment: You will still have memory leak even if you remove `temp->key = key`, or if your remove `CString` out of that class completely. The leak is caused by `Node* temp = new Node;` it's not because of `CString`. You have acknowledged this in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani yes I agree with you that the cause of the memory leak is not the reference counting behavior of `CString`. I included the reference counting behavior information because I thought that was a possible candidate for what was causing the memory leak to be reported. How was it causing the report? I have no idea, it was only speculation.